# Does a web app stored in firebase hosting still need to authenticate

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

If I store my web app in firebase hosting, do I still need to authenticate if I want to access my firebase database, even if they are both in the same project?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the web app that authenticates, but *the users of your web app*. If you don't want them to authenticate, you can easily turn allow anonymous access in the security rules for your database; see the [`public` rules in this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart). But you'll be opening your database up for abuse that way.

Comment: The web app will not be publicly accessible. I want to make it like a dealer in a card game that I'm trying to make. The app will subscribe to changes made to a node in my database, then set the value of another node, so that other devices can proceed.

Comment: Firebase is a cloud-hosted database. It is by definition publicly accessible. There is no way to prevent that.